# Citation for rewriting non-degenerate bilinear form so that the Gram matrix is an anti-diagonal

Tags: bilinear-form

For a paper, I am looking for a reference in the literature for the following theorem:

Given a symmetric non degenerate bilinear form $\phi$  on a finite dimensional vector space , with $\dim  >1$, and $\phi(e_i, e_j)=0$ if $i+j>n+1$, there is a basis of $_1$,...,$_$ of V such that the matrix  associated to $\phi$  with respect to $_1$,...,$_$ is the anti-diagonal matrix.

A proof for this statement is given at

[Anti-diagonal matrix symmetric bilinear form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921563/anti-diagonal-matrix-symmetric-bilinear-form)

(though the original poster left out an important condition)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by anti-diagonal? Don't you mean diagonal?

Comment: It is false. There is no basis of $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\a&0\end{bmatrix}$ represents the Euclidean dot product.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the post to indicate that the values of the form below the anti-diagonal are all zero.